# Move images with mouse click instead of mouse over JQuery Smooth Div Scroll

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

Great plugin! I am trying to figure out a way to have the images in the slider move only on a mouse click instead of moving during a mouse over. Is there any way to make this happen?

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: This is the plugin I assume OP is using, since it was stated. http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

Answer (score 0):

What i can tell you is you will need to edit `jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.2.js` try searching for `.bind("mouseover"` and change `mouseover` to `click`

Comment: No, because that's what you need to do :) It may not be **that** simple, but I have certainly pointed you in the correct direction.

Comment: Actually, I see that the slider is using this script instead: jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.2-min.js and changing to click for bind seems to work. However, once I click there are other functions that scroll with mouseover or mouseup or mousedown. Do you know if I can change those to click as well?

Comment: change that to `jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.2.js` - the two files are the same, but the `-min` file is more compressed. Once you get it working the way you want, you can re-minify the code and paste it back into the `-min` file. (http://jscompress.com/)

Comment: I am not actually familiar with the library. I just took a quick peak at its git repository. You **can** change whatever you want - do it and see what happens.